# PHP issues with mysqli extension and PDO, pdo_mysql extensions

Tags: nginx, php, centos7

A script I am going to install requires either the mysqli extension or both the PDO and pdo_mysql extensions.

VPS running Centos 7 with Nginx.

PHP installation:

```
rpm -qa | grep php
php70w-fpm-7.0.17-1.w7.x86_64
php70w-opcache-7.0.17-1.w7.x86_64
php70w-common-7.0.17-1.w7.x86_64
```

When trying to install php-mysqli I've got the following output:

```
yum install php-mysqli
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.softaculous.com
 * epel: fr2.rpmfind.net
 * extras: ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de
 * updates: ftp.plusline.de
 * webtatic: sp.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php71w-mysql.x86_64 0:7.1.3-1.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php71w-pdo(x86-64) for package: php71w-mysql-7.1.3-1.w7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php71w-pdo.x86_64 0:7.1.3-1.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php71w-common(x86-64) = 7.1.3-1.w7 for package: php71w-pdo-7.1.3-1.w7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php71w-common.x86_64 0:7.1.3-1.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php71w-common-7.1.3-1.w7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.1
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php71w-common conflicts with php70w-common-7.0.17-1.w7.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

So it seems to me there is a conflict between php71w-common and php70w-common.

Php71w is installed but not in use.

I have tried to install something else and got a similar error, this time with php-common-5.4.16:

```
yum install php-devel php-pear mysql-devel httpd-devel
Processing Conflict: php70w-common-7.0.17-1.w7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.0
Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
```

I am very new to unix and php, so please forgive me if my question is silly.

What can I do to get the mysqli extension or the PDO, pdo_mysql extensions working and is there an easy way to remove php 5.4.16 and php 7.1 to avoid such conflicts in the future.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://tecadmin.net/install-php7-on-centos7/). To install additional extension, use `sudo yum --enablerepo=remi-php71 install php-mysqli php-pdo php-pdo_mysql`